# query to Increment column value in merge/update oracle query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g

I have a ORACLE table - AccountDetails - request_id must be unique

```
Account_No   Request_Id   Issue_date    Amount   
 1              567       20150607      $156     
 2              789       20170406      $765     
 3                        20170216      $897     
 4              987       20160525      $345    
 5              564        20170112      $556    
 6                         20171118      $987
```

Need to update the request_id where request id is null  with below logic. I Need to get the maximum request id and need to update the request id (max request id + 1) WHERE request_id is null and request_id must be unique in the table. So the result should be.

```
Account No   Request_Id   Issue_date    Amount  
  1              567       20150607      $156     
  2              789       20170406      $765     
  3              988       20170216      $897     
  4              987       20160525      $345     
  5              564       20170112      $556     
  6              989       20171118      $987
```

Tried with below query but the value is not getting increment. Same value is getting updated in request_id (988).

```
   MERGE INTO account_details tgt
  USING (SELECT account_no,
            CASE WHEN request_id IS NULL THEN 1 + max(request_id) 
                 ELSE request_id
            END request_id,
            issue_date,
            amount,
            ROWID r_id
     FROM   accountdetails) src
ON (tgt.rowid = src.r_id)
 WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET tgt.request_id = src.request_id;
```

Comment: You don't care which account gets 988 and which gets 999, right? (You shouldn't care - the request id should be a non-null, unique number, with no relevant relationship to anything else in the data.)

Comment: yes I dont care which account gets 988 or 999.. just I need to update with unique id's by getting the maximum request id and increment by 1

Comment: how are the request ids in that table being populated for those rows that already have them? If it's the "max id + 1" method, I highly recommend you switch to using a sequence instead - it'll be far better for concurrent inserts/updates!

Answer (score 2):

You need to generate the numbers 1, 2, 3, ... somehow. Here is one way. The "source" table for the MERGE is just picking up the ROWID for the rows that must be updated (those where the request id is NULL), and records the ROWNUM as the row is generated. Then the UPDATE clause uses this ROWNUM.

```
merge into accountdetails
using ( select rowid as rid, rownum as rn from accountdetails where request_id is null ) x
  on (accountdetails.rowid = x.rid)
when matched then update
  set request_id = (select max(request_id) from accountdetails) + x.rn
;
```

It may seem as though the `MAX(request_id)` is calculated repeatedly, once for each updated row; but the optimizer is smart enough to recognize that this calculated value is "constant" (it doesn't vary from one row to the next), so the value is really only calculated once.

**EDIT**:  As Boneist points out in a Comment below, there is no need for the `MERGE` statement in this problem. An `UPDATE` statement works better and is much simpler.

```
update   accountdetails
  set    request_id = (select max(request_id) from accountdetails) + rownum
  where  request_id is null
;
```

Comment: why a merge? An update would be simpler, surely? e.g. `update accountdetails set request_id = rownum + (select max(...)....) where request_id is null`

Comment: @Boneist - You are absolutely right. I wasn't even thinking - I just thought about how to generate the "proper" values to populate the column. In this case `update` would be much simpler and probably faster, too. If you post that as an Answer, I will delete mine, as it is indeed inferior.

Comment: Nah, you update yours with the update and I'll delete my comments *{:-)

Comment: I will update the answer, but you must keep the Comment since I will reference it.